# How to preview wireframes/design made with Keynote that are larger than my monitor resolution?

Tags: wireframe, visual-design

Many blog posts are recommending wire-framing with Keynote, since you don't have to spend in buying in another tool. So while trying out this with Keynote I hit a problem.

If my page is longer like 1024 x 2048, how do I present/preview the page in actual size with Keynote? The moment I press 'Play Slideshow' the whole page will be squeezed in a single screen. Is there any trick to view the page in actual size (with scroll) other than exporting into PDF?

Answer (score 1):

Presentation view in Keynote (or PowerPoint, or any other slide-deck creation software) wasn't designed to support wireframes so it's natural to have such problems with it. It always scales slides to fit the screen and there's no way around it.

As for "canvas" size, you can extend the page length through the printing options but you're still dealing with paper inches not screen pixels. In other words, presentation software can't be used for even medium fidelity prototyping because the proportions will be skewed depending on the screen size.

Comment: I was wondering how the big agencies like Edenspeikerman uses keynote to design (beyond wireframes) and recommend others: http://edenspiekermann.com/en/blog/espi-at-work-the-power-of-keynote

Comment: FWIW, you can use MS Word or Adobe InDesign for wireframe with the same success as long as you have all of the building blocks available. The difference is that tools created for print design work off inches & DPI while wireframing tools work off pixels & PPI. Translating physical distances into paddings & margins isn't simple. However, the best tool is the one you've mastered.

Comment: Yes, the best tool is the one you've mastered! I was using Axure with previous company. That is the best among the tools I have used for mockups ( others being Balsamiq, Fireworks, InDesign,...). But recently I moved to do my own design studio, so searching for low cost tools :). Almost managing with Balsamiq. But I would like to go a level up with style libraries etc. Thats when I saw the above post and asking around how to go around with these small blocks. :)

Answer (score 1):

I realise this isn't much different to exporting to PDF, but what I have done in the past is to export as PNG and then open the PNG in a web browser. It puts the wireframe into context and gives you natural scrolling ability.